# Can not install cleverhans version 3.1.0

Tags: python, cleverhans

I am trying to install cleverhans verion 3.1.0 but getting following error

pip install cleverhans==3.1.0

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cleverhans==3.1.0 (from versions: 2.1.0, 3.0.0, 3.0.0.post0, 3.0.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cleverhans==3.1.0

I want to access random_lp_vector method in 3.1.0 version which I am unable to access if I try in 3.0.1 also Is there any option available for adversarial training in the latest version which is 4.0.0

Please kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not able to install version 3.1.0 via pip install as that version is not listed in [Python package index(PyPI)](https://pypi.org/project/cleverhans/#history).

You can download the source code of the required version 3.1.0 or 4.0.0 from [github](https://github.com/cleverhans-lab/cleverhans) directly and install using `setup.py`